# Stegnography Tool - StegDetect (error: Quantization table 0x00 was not defined)

Tags: jpeg, steganography

I meet an error while using stegdetect program to detect if my a.jpg file has content hidden inside. The error is "error: Quantization table 0x00 was not defined". Can anybody explain to me what this error is about? Please help me with this error. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Stegbreak command:
[image]

Comment: Was the jpeg compressed lossless? In that case I guess no compression takes place and these headers become optional.

Comment: @AloisKraus, I am not sure if the image is compressed lossless. Because this is a file in a forensic image given to by lecturer for assignment. I can't use stegbreak command on the file, because it gives me the error too. May I know are there ways to resolve this?

Comment: Hard to tell if the tool has a problem or your command line misses some flags.

Comment: @AloisKraus, I have edited my post which contains a picture of the stegbreak command that i have used. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your JPEG file is corrupted. `stegbreak` utility clearly states what before marker `0xDB` (Define quantization table) you have extra 67 bytes.

I think what before definition of first (0x00) quantization table there was a comment block which is malformed (has more data than was indicated in block header).

You can try to use [JPEGsnoop](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-snoop.html) tool to analyze file and see what is exactly gong wrong.

Or you can use `jpegtran` tool from libjpeg to losslessy reencode image and fix its headers (but you may loose all metadata which are not part of image itself).